# What progress has been made in computerized bridge play?

Tags: games-of-chance

Computer programs have been produced for games such as Chess, Go, Poker, StarCraft 2, Dota. The best ones, Deep Blue and AlphaGo , AlphaZero, Pluribus,... are now considered better than the best human players. More to the point, the computers' game results have been influencing human play.

Apparently, computers are not yet better than human players in Bridge. There can be computer simulations of various hands and hypothetical opposing hands. But what progress have computers made in playing human players in tournaments? Have any new theories of bidding or play evolved as a result of computer-human interaction in Bridge?

---

This is question was [asked at Board & Card Games Q&A](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/50507/what-progress-has-been-made-in-computerized-bridge-play) however I think here it might get better answer